# UseEffect not working provided I am passing an object to it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

even though the **ThemeChange object** changes everytime the App component gets rerendered... I still don't know why it is not causing **useEffect** to execute whenever I either *change the number* or *click on toggleTheme button*... I am severely confused

```
import React,{useState, useMemo, useEffect} from 'react'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false),
  [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
  
  const SlowFunction = num => {
    for(let i=1; i<=10000; ++i) {}
    return num*2
  }
  
  const TwiceNo = useMemo(() => {
    return SlowFunction(number)
  }, [number])

   const ThemeChange = {
      backgroundColor : dark ? 'black' : 'white',
      color : dark ? 'white' : 'black' 
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('theme was changed!')
  }, [ThemeChange])
  

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" onChange = {e => {setNumber(parseInt(e.target.value), console.log(e))}} />
      <button onClick={() => setDark(e => !e)}>toggle theme</button>
      <div style={ThemeChange}>{TwiceNo}</div>
    </div>

);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This isn't valid code; you cannot access `ThemeChange` before it's defined

Comment: With that small error fixed, I cannot [reproduce this](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-engelbart-v29i09?file=/src/App.js). Each time state changes it logs _"theme was changed!"_ as expected

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh your solution works. What is wrong?
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-booth-ehc2ql?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ProllyGeek it is working because i indeed edited it to make ThemeChange object come before useEffect hook!

Answer (score -1):

Javascript objects will not be the same when your component is rerender ( google search more about that) -> Your effect will run every time component rerender because the deps is different. Try to specify the deps.

Like this

`useEffect(() => { console.log(Date.now(), "theme was changed!"); }, [ThemeChange.backgroundColor, ThemeChange.color]);`

or even better version use this `useEffect(() => { console.log(Date.now(), "theme was changed!"); }, [dark]);`